# Unity3d Networking: What happens to networking when the player receives a phone call?

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming

I am building a **multiplayer, turn based cards game**. Since the answer to these question is not available in the docs, I am asking it here:

**The game uses Unity's networking HLAPI (NetworkClient and NetworkServer), and the client & server communicate exclusively with NetworkMessages, no RPC is used.** What happens when:

(a) The client on an android smartphone is connected to the server & playing, and the player suddenly receives a call? With the client disconnect, or will it continue to send messages, or will it stall, not accepting any messages?

(b) The player is playing over 3G and suddenly decides to switch over to Wi-Fi with the game still running. Will the client disconnect, or will the game somehow continue to run and the client stays connected to the server?

Comment: The second case will disconnect the client, that's for sure... but I don't know about the phone call behaviour, probably depends on how Android handles the activities (e.g., if the user sets the max. background activities to 0, it would restart the game)

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this question.  But it's difficult to see why you don't just try it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) If you are using 3g & receive call then , its obvious player will get disconnected .

b) If you are on wifi and receive call then , you will not get disconnected if your android can handle keeping your game in memory .

c) If you switch network , the disconnection will depend upon game server .
Server will handle the part if the player reconnection should be whole new or just reconnect were he left .

Looking to your game , the server should reconnect as new connection .